# How does being spherically symmetric imply this particular form for the metric?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, vector-fields, lie-algebra

If $(M, g)$ is a 4-dimensional Lorentzian manifold whose isometry group contains a subgroup isomorphic to
$\text{SO}(3)$, then we can put $g$ in the form:
$$
g = -A(r, t) \mathrm{d} t ^2 + B(r, t) \mathrm{d} r ^2 + C(r, t) \mathrm{d} \Omega ^2
$$
where $\mathrm{d} \Omega ^2$ is well known metric on the sphere. My question is how exactly does being
spherically symmetric imply this form? I know that if $G \subset \text{Iso}(M)$ is isomorphic to
$\text{SO}(3)$ then it must have three 1-parameter groups which when differentiated give rise to three Killing
Vector fields $V_i$ which satisfy
\begin{align}
[V_i, V_j] = \epsilon_{ijk} V_k.
\end{align}
These form an involutive distribution, so their integral manifolds foliate the spacetime by the Frobenius
theorem. Here is where I get confused trying to connect the induced metric on the foliations to the metric on
the sphere. The first thing I do not know is how to show that the integral manifolds are ''spheres'', where I
imagine that a sphere through a point is just the orbit of that point under $G$. Next, how do I coordinate
these leaves so that the metric looks like that of the Euclidean sphere?